# Error with default Namespace

Tags: xml, soap

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://data.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Sachin>
              <aRoute>
                <name>ToTheTop</name>
                <grade xsi:type="FrencGrade">
                <gradeNumber>7</gradeNumber>
                <gradeModifier>a</gradeModifier>
                </grade>
            </aRoute>
     </Sachin>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When i am trying to send request with default namespace an getting error response as Unmarshalling Error.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring >Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element </faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You might try putting the default namespace declaration on the `Sachin` element directly in case it's not surviving extraction from the SOAP envelope.

Comment: Yes am trying to put default namespace on sachin element .in that case it is throwing unmarshalling error unexpected element.

Comment: Can you show the WSDL?  Does it definitely expect all the elements to be in that namespace, or does it maybe expect just the `Sachin` element to be in the namespace and its children not?

Comment: <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="Uri" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to see the full schema to be sure but from a combination of the small fragment of WSDL you gave in a comment above:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="Uri" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

with its use of `elementFormDefault="unqualified"`, and the example request using `xsi:type`, I suspect that you're working with a schema that expects the `Sachin` element to be in the target namespace but its children to be in *no* namespace.  The meaning of "unqualified" here is that top-level element declarations take the target namespace of the schema, but "local" declarations inside a complexType do not.  So if the schema looks like

```
<element name="Sachin" type="SachinType"/><!-- top-level declaration -->

<complexType name="SachinType">
  <sequence>
    <!-- local declaration -->
    <element name="aRoute" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:routeType"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="routeType">
  <sequence>
    <element name="name" type="string"/>
    <element name="grade" type="gradeType" />
  </sequence>
</complexType>

<!-- etc. -->
```

then a valid instance would have to be

```
<u:Sachin xmlns:u="Uri">
  <aRoute>
    <name>...</name>
    <grade ....></grade>
  </aRoute>
</u:Sachin>
```

Using `xmlns="Uri"` would put `aRoute` and its children in the namespace, which is not what the schema expects.